# How to differentiate real Yu-Gi-Oh! cards from fakes

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Simply, how do I tell the differences between real and fake *Yu-Gi-Oh!* cards? The cards I have seem to be legit, but it's either all legit or all counterfeit. Any tips?

Comment: I'd recommend buying a few legit boosters from a reputable local game store, so you know what "real" cards look/feel like.  If you're just playing with friends at your house, real/fake shouldn't matter (as much).

Comment: @John, it turns out my friend had some! But they looks so fake... Extreme discoloration, Typos, there is _fake_ written all over it. Rank 7 _Number 39: Utopia_, and _Rank nine _Super Dreadnought Cannon Gustav Mac?_ Yeah! with sarcasm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The *Yu-Gi-Oh!* wikia lists the most common tells

There is [an article on the *Yu-Gi-Oh!* wikia](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Counterfeit) that lists the most common tells with counterfeit cards. Without duplicating the whole list, a couple of the major ones appear to be:

- The [Eye of Anubis Hologram](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Eye_of_Anubis_Hologram) is missing
- Incorrect card format (e.g. Levels on a Spell/Trap card)
- Misspellings
- Passcode text in the bottom left corner missing (although some legitimate cards are missing it too)
- An unusual glossiness or feel

You can also detect counterfeit sets of cards by:

- An incorrect [cover card](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Cover_Card)
- An entire deck within a deck tin (since real deck tins only included booster packs or promo cards)
- An unusual ratio of monsters to spell/trap cards (e.g. 1 trap card and 15 monsters)

### There was a lawsuit where a legitimate company sold counterfeit cards

In 2008, Konami filed a lawsuit against Vintage Sports Cards. They were legally allowed to resell *Yu-Gi-Oh!* cards in boxes where booster packs were sold alongside three Ultra-Rare cards. Unfortunately, some of those Ultra-Rare cards were counterfeit. [From an article about it](http://icv2.com/articles/comics/view/13988/counterfeit-yu-gi-oh-rares):

> The counterfeit “rare” cards, which are clearly visible in the Vintage Sports packaging, use a different paper type and protective varnish than those used in real Yu-Gi-Oh! cards and the holographic security foil also differs from that used on the real Konami cards.